# useEffect does not allow me to update an array inside my component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have two issues, the first one was when I wanted to pass an array of objects from a parent component to a child component, something like this:

```
function DropdownSome ({options, placeholder, someNum}) {
   const [value, setValue] = useState (options)

    return (
           <Dropdown as = {ButtonGroup}>
                  <Dropdown.Toggle as = {CustomToggle}>
                        {placeholder}
                  </Dropdown.Toggle>
                  <Dropdown.Menu as = {CustomMenu}>
                      {value.map ((r, index) =>
                          <Dropdown.ItemText key = {r.id}>
                                 <Counter 
                                   index={index}
                                   someNum={someNum}
                                   ...
                                 />
                          </Dropdown.ItemText>
                       )}
                   </Dropdown.Menu>
            </Dropdown>
       )
}
export default DropdownSome;
```

Here I couldn't set an array with useState (hooks) because it didn't finish passing my constant value. Then solve this using the useEffect hook, like this:

```
 useEffect (() => {
        setValue (options); // this worked to pass options in value
    }, [options])
```

Then I was able to pass my array to my const value, and I was able to use value within my child component. In this component I need to set a value inside my array (setValue (array[someIndex].qty= someNum)). My second issue now is that the useEffect hook is always updating the value of my array to its initial state and this does not allow me to update my array within my child component (array[someIndex].qty // always set at the initial value). I've only tried running useEffect once like this:

```
useEffect (() => {
        setValue (options); // this doesn't work to pass options in value
    }, [])
```

but doing this, my array again fails to pass to my constant value and I feel like I'm stuck here. I've also tried clearing useEffect so that the setValue only runs once, but useEffect keeps setting my variable to its initial state.

```
useEffect (() => {
        const counterInterval = setInterval (() => {
            setValue (options);
        });

        return () => clearInterval (counterInterval);
    }, [options]);
```

I am new to this and some hook life cycle topics are taking me some time to understand, but I hope someone has gone through something similar who can advise me.

Comment: Where are you wanting to `setValue(array[someIndex].qty= someNum)`? It's typically a React anti-pattern to store passed props in local component state (as @hellogoodnight points out), but then this leave the door option to you seeming to still want to *update* the options values. Where does `options` live as a source of truth and where are you wanting to update it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use useState or useEffect for your component, as far as I can see.
Just do this:

```
function DropdownSome ({options, placeholder, someNum}) {


    return (
           <Dropdown as = {ButtonGroup}>
                  <Dropdown.Toggle as = {CustomToggle}>
                        {placeholder}
                  </Dropdown.Toggle>
                  <Dropdown.Menu as = {CustomMenu}>
                      {(options || []).map ((r, index) =>
                          <Dropdown.ItemText key = {r.id}>
                                 <Counter 
                                   index={index}
                                   someNum={someNum}
                                   ...
                                 />
                          </Dropdown.ItemText>
                       )}
                   </Dropdown.Menu>
            </Dropdown>
       )
}
export default DropdownSome;
```

The `|| []` is added to handle the case that options are not set when the component mounts (the issue I assume you are trying to handle with your hooks).

Answer (score 0):

This is not really clear, but guess you want to get array of options from parent and then store it as value to modify only value and options in parent to remain unchanged.
In such case you can try to initiate value with empty array.  `const [value, setValue] = useState ([]);`
and then in useEffect update value only if value.length=0
like this:

```
useEffect (() => {
        if (value.legth===0) setValue(options); 
    }, [options])
```

If you need to modify options upon change in value than check abt callbacks.